# SQL Server 2008R2 Cluster: Spread tempdb over several files AND shrink original single file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

On my SQL 2008 R2 active/passive cluster, I've received an error message regarding I/O requests on tempdb.mdf taking longer than 15seconds. Googled that and it as suggested I spread tempdb over several files. I have 2 4-core CPUs and figured I'd spreaad tempdb over 8 files.
The current tempdb.mdf is 8GB in size, most of which is unused space. I figured I'd start out with all 8 files being 512MB with filegrowth set to 64MB increments.

Ive executed the T-SQL to create the extra files and set the original tempdb.mdf's initial size to 512MB. My question is:

If I now rollover the cluster to the other node, will the tempdb.mdf file shrink to 512MB?
And will this allow the SQL server to spread tempdb across all 8 files?

Or must I perform any other operation?

Or - hope this is not the case - have I made a mistake that means the SQL server will crash when I rollover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if anyone will read this, but... I performed the rollover this weekend without problems. All 8 tempdb-files are now 512MB. "Case closed"